# How to make navgationBar hidden again?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I am developing an App in which facing some difficulties, after searching a lot solutions, but it is still not working.

First, I create an App like this

[image: nav bar hidden]

I use the following codes to make the `navgationBar` hidden in `viewWillAppear:` method

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]
                                              forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

But after I take a photo using `UIImagePickerController`, the `navgationBar` will appear on the screen,

like the this:
[image: nav bar appear]

So, how can I make the navgation bar always hidden? Thanks a lot..

=============== Update =============

I also used UIImagePickerController to choose photo from library, while it works well. After I have chosen and back to this viewController, the bar still hide. It's really strange.

Comment: why you are not using something like `[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];`

Comment: I have used. But it does't work either.

Comment: @W.LeeLom You need Navigation Bar hidden in the image Picker also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want hide your navigation Bar once you go back to your viewController after picking image use this two callbacks method

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
   //Your code....
   [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:YES];
}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
   //Your code....
   [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:YES];
}
```

But if you want remove the navigation bar from your `UIImagePickerViewController` the you should subclass the `UIImagePickerViewController` and in your custom UIImagePicker something like this

## .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomImagePickerController : UIImagePickerController

@end
```

## .m

```
#import "CustomImagePickerController.h"

@interface CustomImagePickerController ()

@end

@implementation CustomImagePickerController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:YES];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

and then use this class as your `UIImagePickerController`

Hope this helps

Comment: Hello, thanks for your solution, but it does't work either. I debug this find the white view is the "UIVisualEffectView", which cause the problem.

Comment: The debug window shows, [image.png](http://upload-images.jianshu.io/upload_images/1156494-4cd902b8beb3fa30.png?imageMogr2/auto-orient/strip%7CimageView2/2/w/1240), I hope i can explain it.

Answer (score 0):

How about embedding your view controller in a navigation controller from the interface builder. Then create a new Navigation Controller file and assign the Navigation Controller in the interface builder to this new class.

In this class just set the bar to hidden and since your initial view controllers will be embedded in it it should constantly remain hidden.

Comment: Sry... I use the Xib + codes, I don't use the storyboard.